# Существует ли редактор кода работающий через браузер

Tags: node.js, сервер, редактор, браузер

У меня есть сервер с доступом по `ssh`, но через `ssh` крайне неудобно заливать файлы и править код. Появилась идея написать редактор запустить его на сервере под отдельным портом, с помощью которого можно будет заливать файлы и править код прямо через браузер. Но не хочется изобретать велосипедов. Может уже что-нибудь подобное написано? И мне стоит только установить и пользоваться?

P.S. Нашёл [терминал](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-terminal), который работает через браузер, но это всего лишь терминал и у меня так и не получилось его запустить как следует на `localhost`.

Comment: Конечно существует. В гитхабе, например. Но вы хотите очень странного. Лучше научится нормально заливать файлы и/или редактировать файлы на сервере

Comment: Примонтируйте удаленную файловую систему как локальную папку и используйте любой редактор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если основная цель "крайне неудобно заливать файлы и править код"
возьмите свою любимую IDE(к примеру phpStorm), и настройте "удаленный проект" выбрав подключение по ssh\sftp.
даже notepad++ умеет, код правится у вас на машине, и загружается на сервер. Заливать файлы через тот же ide

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал об этом. `phpStorm` платный. Есть редактор, который сможет подключиться с серверу по `ssh` вывести структуру проекта в виде дерева, по которому можно кликать и редактировать файлы? :)

Comment: тот же notepad++ )) и другие (кроме шторма другими не пользовался)
https://i.gyazo.com/765557d04a5ab31334ed8b8bbbed8cf2.png

Comment: шикарно! Но все-таки подожду некоторое время. Вдруг кто-нибудь найдет тот самый браузерный редактор. Кстати у этого редактора будет одно весомое преимущество. Для доступа к сайту будет нужен только браузер. Например, у меня в институте без прав админа `notepad++` поставить не получится.

Comment: Может быть подойдет Secure Shell https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=ru